# Build DC/DC (Buck) Converter using 555 timer

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, 555, buck

I saw a design for a 12V DC to 5V DC buck converter using a 555 timer on http://www.simple-electronics.com/2011/10/12v-to-5v-converter-555ic-mosfet.html. Is this a good design to use towards my smps? I've been trying to design a 120vac to 5vdc (capable of 2amps) smps for a few months now and struggling with the pwm portion.

Answer (score 6):

The circuit that you linked is a horrible voltage converter. It has no feedback in the circuit to dynamically adjust the duty cycle to regulate the output voltage. The additional circuit on that web page showing to use a power transistor with a zener diode to compensate for the short comings of the 555 circuit is also a horrible approach.

There are a plethora of available switching power supply controller chips and modules available that will do a far more superior job of converting the voltage from 12 to 5 volts. Get one and use that instead.

Comment: Also, this design does NOT provide galvanic isolation, so it is unsuitable for 99% of the use cases the OP is talking about (120VAC to low voltage).